# Why recovered patients develop lung disease due Covid-19?

Tags: covid-19, virus, lungs, infectious-diseases, recovery

In this link

https://www.dw.com/en/covid-19-recovered-patients-have-partially-reduced-lung-function/a-52859671

we can see

> Now researchers in Hong Kong have said that recovered coronavirus patients can be left with damaged lungs.
>
> A small study of 12 patients discharged from hospital showed that two or three had reduced lung function. However, it is too early to confirm any long-term effects.
>
> "In some patients, lung function could decline by about 20 to 30% after recovery," says Dr. Owen Tsang Tak-yin, medical director of the Infectious Diseases Centre at Princess Margaret Hospital in Hong Kong.
>
> Computer tomography have shown fluid- or debris-filled sacs in the lungs, which may get progressively worse as the illness develops.

What can determine the *long term effects*?

Why can this:

"In some patients, lung function could decline by about 20 to 30% after recovery," happen?

Are elderly more likely to this? or it could happen to anyone?

Does this only happen if you had severe symptoms?

Comment: You've asked four questions, none of which does anyone have good answers for yet.

Comment: @CareyGregory could you share the link mentioned in my question to OP this of [question](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21685/whats-the-best-time-of-year-to-purposely-contract-covid?noredirect=1#comment41430_21685), currently I have less that 50 and cannot comment.

Comment: I think this video might have an answer for you, but just posting a video isn’t enough for an answer: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=BtN-goy9VOY

Comment: @nick012000 thanks. You could post the video and give a brief explanation of what is it about, that'd be ok as an answer me thinks

Comment: There's another reason: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ventilator-associated_lung_injury - I heard this in an interview with a doctor in TV news, so no proper source -> comment only. But the doctor explained that many Covid-19 patients need ventilation very long and they often have extensive pneumonia which means that the ventilation must use high pressure to keep sufficient oxygen into the patients to keep them alive. But injury risk increases with pressure and with time at the ventilator.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX well.. what catastrophic situation is this.. :/ Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

The best theoretical model we have is that the SARS and SARS-CoV-2 viruses knock out the ACE2 receptor found on numerous tissues including alveolar cells, and myocytes, and intestinal luminal cells.

If those cells have died then they need to be replaced, and if and until when that happens there will be reduced organ function.

CT scans of recovered patients show some have ground glass changes pointing to extensive damage and scarring which may be irreversible.

https://www.businessinsider.com.au/coronavirus-recovery-damage-lung-function-gasping-air-hong-kong-doctors-2020-3?r=US&IR=T

https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2020/03/biography-new-coronavirus/608338/

Comment: Thank you for your very informative answer.

Comment: "SARS-CoV-2 viruses knock out the ACE2 receptor found on numerous tissues including alveolar cells, and myocytes, and intestinal luminal cells" the knock out you mention here, is for anyone (young/old, healthy, ill, etc)?

Comment: One would think so but no one knows why some populations do better than others.

Comment: oh ok. Here "If those cells have died then they need to be replaced, and if and until when that happens there will be reduced organ function." why would the cells die?

Comment: Viruses hijack cellular machinery to create copies of the virus

Comment: "CT scans of recovered patients show some have ground glass changes pointing to extensive damage and scarring which may be irreversible." what can lead to extensive damage and scarring?

Comment: @America A combination of damage done by the virus itself and by the immune system trying to control it. It's a bit like asking "why is a city damaged while war is going on in it?".

Comment: @BryanKrause ok ok :p It's just that I was thinking that if someone caught the virus but only have mild symptoms and after some days they recover, then why would they have some damage in their lungs? or extensive damage or scarring?

Comment: Do you have evidence or a reference for the claim that someone with mild symptoms would have extensive damage or scarring?

Comment: @BryanKrause nop, that's why I was asking Graham Chiu, that "what can lead to extensive damage and scarring?". Anyway, it doesn't sounds reasonable that someone with mild symptoms might end up with 'extensive damage or scarring', maybe not even any damage on their lungs, right? :) so why to worry.. no point

Answer (score 1):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtN-goy9VOY) by Kurzgesagt gives a good overview of how the COVID-19 infection process works. The damage it causes to the lungs seems to the result of it damaging the cells that create a protective lining of your lungs; this happens both directly as a result of their infections of these cells, as well as by causing the immune system to attack healthy cells. By killing large numbers of these cells, bacteria that this lining would normally protect from are now able to invade the lungs and cause issues like pneumonia. Additionally, the damage that is done during the initial phase can cause significant amounts of scarring within the lungs as the body tries to recover from the damage.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer